# Jsoup getElementsByClass gives size 0 Elements

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that fetches weather information from weather.com by using JSoup. This is what I have so far:

```
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class WeatherComHandler {
    private Element ForeCastDiv;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WeatherComHandler wch = new WeatherComHandler("http://www.weather.com/weather/today/Brussels+BEXX0005:1:BE");
        wch.getTodaysForeCast();
    }

    public WeatherComHandler(String url) {
        getForeCastDiv(url);
    }

    private void getForeCastDiv(String url) {
        try {            
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            ForeCastDiv = doc.getElementById("wx-forecast-container");
        }    catch(Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getTodaysForeCast() {
        System.out.println(ForeCastDiv.toString());
        System.out.println(ForeCastDiv.hasClass("wx-data-part wx-first"));
        Elements todaysElements = ForeCastDiv.getElementsByClass("wx-data-part wx-first");
        System.out.println(todaysElements.size());
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
    <div id="wx-forecast-container"> 
<div class="wx-today wx-module wx-grid3of6"> 
  <div class="wx-title-container"> 
   <h2 class="wx-title"><img src="http://i.imwx.com/common/My.png" /> Forecast for Today</h2> 
   <div class="wx-updated">
    Updated: Oct 28, 5:45pm Local Time
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-promo-links wx-cond wx-severe wx-severe-0"> 
    <ul class="wx-links"> 
  <li class="wx-icon wx-cond wx-desktop"> <a class="wx-icon wx-cond wx-desktop" href="/apps/desktop-weather" location="" from="today_promo_1" title="Weather on my Desktop">Desktop App</a> </li> 
    </ul> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="wx-weather-details"> 
   <div class="wx-timepart-title wx-first">
  Right Now 
    <div class="wx-module wx-grid1of6 wx-weather wx-love-module wx-cond-bg"> 
  <div class="wx-module-inner"> 
  <div class="wx-icon wx-social wx-balloon-wt-lt wx-clickable wx-love-ugh" data-good="true" data-share-trx="" data-share-icon="http://s.imwx.com/img/common/social/lmw-love.jpg" title="Love My Weather" data-share-desc="It's 55&deg;F, Clear"> 
  <div class="wx-icon wx-social wx-heart"></div> 
  <h4 data-share-title="Love! Right now in Brussels, Belgium"></h4> 
  </div> 
  <div class="wx-icon wx-social wx-balloon-wt-rt wx-clickable wx-love-ugh" data-good="false" data-share-trx="" data-share-icon="http://s.imwx.com/img/common/social/lmw-ugg.jpg" title="Don't Love My Weather" data-share-desc="It's 55&deg;F, Clear"> 
  <h4 data-share-title="Ugh! Right now in Brussels, Belgium"></h4> 
  </div> 
  </div> 
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-timepart-title">
  Earlier Today 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-timepart-title">
    Tonight
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-data-part wx-first"> 
    <img src="http://s.imwx.com/v.20131006.214956/img/wxicon/120/31.png" height="120" width="120" alt="Clear" class="wx-weather-icon" /> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-data-part"> 
    <img src="http://s.imwx.com/v.20131006.214956/img/wxicon/120/34.png" height="120" width="120" alt="Fair / Windy" class="wx-weather-icon" /> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-data-part"> 
    <img src="http://s.imwx.com/v.20131006.214956/img/wxicon/120/29.png" height="120" width="120" alt="Partly Cloudy" class="wx-weather-icon" /> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-data-part wx-first"> 
    <div class="wx-temperature">
  <span itemprop="temperature-fahrenheit">55</span>
  <span class="wx-degrees">&deg;<span class="wx-unit">F</span></span>
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-temperature-label">
  FEELS LIKE 
  <span itemprop="feels-like-temperature-fahrenheit">55</span>&deg;
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-data-part"> 
    <div class="wx-temperature">
  62
  <span class="wx-degrees">&deg;</span>
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-temperature-label">
  HIGH AT 11:45 AM
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-data-part"> 
    <div class="wx-temperature">
  47
  <span class="wx-degrees">&deg;</span>
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-temperature-label">
  LOW
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-data-part wx-first"> 
    <div class="wx-phrase ">
  Clear
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-obs-qualifier "> 
  <span class="wx-hide" itemprop="observation-qualifier">OQ1190</span> 
  <span class="wx-hide" itemprop="observation-qualifier-severity">2</span> 
  <span itemprop="observation-qualifier-phrase">Locations nearby are reporting rain with wind.</span> 
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-data-part"> 
    <div class="wx-phrase ">
  Fair / Windy
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-data-part"> 
    <div class="wx-phrase ">
  Partly Cloudy
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-data-part wx-first"> 
    <h6 class="wx-label">Past 24-hr Precip:</h6> 
    <div class="wx-data">
  0.34 in 
  <span class="wx-estimated">(est.)</span>
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-data-part"> 
    <h6 class="wx-label"></h6> 
    <div class="wx-data"></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-data-part"> 
    <h6 class="wx-label">Chance of <span class="wx-firstletter">rain</span></h6> 
    <div class="wx-data">
  <span class="wx-icon wx-raindrop"></span>20%
    </div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-collapsible"> 
    <div class="wx-data-part wx-first wx-wind"> 
  <h6 class="wx-label">Wind:</h6> 
  <div class="wx-data"> 
  <div class="wx-icon wx-dir-arrow-sm wind-dir-SW"></div> 
  <div class="wx-wind-label">
  SW at 17 mph
  </div> 
  </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-data-part wx-wind"> 
  <h6 class="wx-label"></h6> 
  <div class="wx-data"> 
  <div class="wx-wind-label"></div> 
  </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-data-part wx-wind"> 
  <h6 class="wx-label">Wind:</h6> 
  <div class="wx-data"> 
  <div class="wx-icon wx-dir-arrow-sm wind-dir-SW"></div> 
  <div class="wx-wind-label">
  SW at 18 mph
  </div> 
  </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-data-part wx-first"> 
  <h6 class="wx-label">Humidity:</h6> 
  <div class="wx-data">
  76%
  </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-data-part"> 
  <h6 class="wx-label"></h6> 
  <div class="wx-data"></div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-data-part"> 
  <h6 class="wx-label">Humidity:</h6> 
  <div class="wx-data">
  82%
  </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-data-part wx-first"> 
  <h6 class="wx-label">UV Index:</h6> 
  <div class="wx-data">
  0 - Low
  </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-data-part"> 
  <h6 class="wx-label"></h6> 
  <div class="wx-data"></div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-data-part"></div> 
    <div class="wx-data-part wx-first "> 
  <h6 class="wx-label"></h6> 
  <p class="wx-text"></p> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-data-part "> 
  <h6 class="wx-label"></h6> 
  <p class="wx-text"></p> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-data-part "> 
  <h6 class="wx-label">Tonight:</h6> 
  <p class="wx-text">Partly cloudy skies. Low 47F. Winds SW at 15 to 25 mph.</p> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-astro-neighbor"> 
  <div class="wx-data-part wx-first"> 
  <h6 class="wx-label">Pressure:</h6> 
  <div class="wx-data">
  <span itemprop="barometric-pressure-incheshg"> 29.59 in </span>
  <span class="wx-icon wx-dir-arrow-sm wx-pressure-steady"></span>
  </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="wx-data-part wx-first wx-dewpoint"> 
  <h6 class="wx-label">Dew Point: <span class="wx-icon wx-long wx-info"> <i>Humidity becomes more noticeable as the dew point rises above 60&deg;F. Readings above 75&deg;F can feel stifling.</i> </span> </h6> 
  <div class="wx-data">
  47&deg;
  </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="wx-data-part wx-first"> 
  <h6 class="wx-label">Visibility:</h6> 
  <div class="wx-data">
  6.0 mi
  </div> 
  </div> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-astro-details"> 
  <h3 class="wx-astro-title">Sun &amp; Moon</h3> 
  <dl class="wx-first"> 
  <dt>
  Sunrise:
  </dt> 
  <dd>
  7:28 am
  </dd> 
  <dt>
  Sunset:
  </dt> 
  <dd>
  5:25 pm
  </dd> 
  </dl> 
  <dl> 
  <dt>
  Moonrise:
  </dt> 
  <dd>
  12:27 am
  </dd> 
  <dt>
  Moonset:
  </dt> 
  <dd>
  2:32 pm
  </dd> 
  </dl> 
  <dl class="wx-moonphase-container"> 
  <dt>
  Moonphase:
  </dt> 
  <dd> 
  <div class="wx-icon wx-moonphase wx-moon-23"></div> 
  <div class="wx-moonphase-label">
  Waning Crescent
  </div> 
  </dd> 
  </dl> 
    </div> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="wx-toggle-collapsible-container"> 
   <div class="wx-toggle-collapsible wx-clickable"> 
    <div class="wx-control wx-expand-control" tracktype="action" trackstr="today_rightnow_showmore">
  <span class="wx-icon wx-arrow wx-mb-lg-dn"></span>Open Weather Details
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-control wx-collapse-control wx-hide" tracktype="action" trackstr="today_rightnow_showless">
  <span class="wx-icon wx-arrow wx-mb-lg-up"></span>Close Weather Details
    </div> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="wx-pagination-linkers"> 
   <div class="wx-next-linker"> 
    <ul class="wx-links"> 
  <li class=""> <a class="" href="/weather/hourbyhour/graph/Brussels+BEXX0005:1:BE" location="" from="today_rightnow-Today_tempGraph_1" title="">Hourly Forecast</a> </li> 
    </ul> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
</div> 
<script>$("#wx-icon wx-long wx-info").attr('title','This is the hover-over text');</script> 
<div id="wunderground-lightbox" class="wx-dialog"> 
  <div class="wx-close" title="Close">
   <div class="wx-icon"></div>
  </div> 
</div> 
<div class="wx-combinedPromo wx-module wx-grid3of6"> 
  <div class="wx-commuter-promo" data-classname="wx-grid-2" from="today-commuterpromo" data-layers="traffic,weather" data-locationinus="false" data-backgroundimageurl="" data-location-zoom="10" data-location-latitude="50.85045" data-location-longitude="4.34878"> 
   <div class="wx-commute-promo-callout-title"> 
    <div class="wx-titleIconHolder"> 
  <img class="wx-titleIcon" src="http://s.imwx.com/img/module/TrafficCams_16x16.png" /> 
    </div> 
    <div class="wx-titleText">
  NEW! Traffic &amp; Commuter Forecast
    </div> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
</div> 
<div class="wx-clear"></div> 
<div class="wx-scroll-tracking wx-scroll-pres" data-modulecode="ScrollTracking1_Today" data-location="BEXX0005:1:BE" data-groupname="weblocal"></div> 
<div class="wx-free-title "> 
  <h3>Latest Stories</h3> 
</div> 
<div id="wx-rightnowsecond-container"> 
  <div id="wx-rightnow-container"> 
   <div class="wx-module wx-mod1 wx-corsican wx-1x155M wx-render-mode" id="mod_4" data-vr-zone="today_beta_Media_top2"> 
    <div class="wx-inner" data-vr-contentbox=""></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="wx-module wx-mod1 wx-corsican wx-1x155M wx-render-mode" id="mod_5" data-vr-zone="today_beta_Media_top1"> 
    <div class="wx-inner" data-vr-contentbox=""></div> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="wx-module wx-trending-stories wx-tabbed-content wx-grid2of6"> 
   <div class="wx-inner"> 
    <h2 class="wx-title">Most Popular</h2> 
    <ul class="wx-tabs" data-vr-zone="Most Popular"> 
  <li class="wx-tab wx-active" data-tab="today" data-vr-contentbox="">Today</li> 
  <li class="wx-tab wx-clickable" data-tab="this_week" data-vr-contentbox="">This Week</li> 
    </ul> 
    <ul class="wx-tab-content" data-tab="today" data-vr-zone="Most Popular"> 
  <li data-vr-contentbox=""><a href="/article/superstorm-sandy-photos-then-and-now-20131024" from="62288_MostPopular_1">Superstorm Sandy: Then and Now (EXCLUSIVE PHOTOS)</a></li>
  <li data-vr-contentbox=""><a href="/article/eerie-nighttime-shots-abandoned-america-20131023" from="62288_MostPopular_2">Eerie Nighttime Shots of Abandoned America</a></li> 
  <li data-vr-contentbox=""><a href="/article/fall-foliage-photos-20131021" from="62288_MostPopular_3">Astounding Fall Photos That Will Make You Say 'Wow!'</a></li> 
  <li data-vr-contentbox=""><a href="/article/nightmares-fear-factory-terrified-reactions-haunted-house-photos-20131001" from="62288_MostPopular_4">Nightmares Fear Factory: Terrified Reactions at Haunted House (PHOTOS)</a></li> 
  <li data-vr-contentbox=""><a href="/article/2013s-worst-cities-asthma-20131025" from="62288_MostPopular_5">The 15 Worst U.S. Cities for Asthma</a></li> 
  <li data-vr-contentbox=""><a href="/video/shocking-end-to-shark-attack-39402" from="62288_MostPopular_6">Shocking End to Shark Attack <span class="wx-icon wx-video wx-trending-video"></span></a></li> 
  <li data-vr-contentbox=""><a href="/video/gigantic-hornets-are-breeding-39247" from="62288_MostPopular_7">Gigantic Hornets Are Breeding <span class="wx-icon wx-video wx-trending-video"></span></a></li> 
  <li data-vr-contentbox=""><a href="/video/18-foot-what-39575" from="62288_MostPopular_8">18-Foot WHAT? <span class="wx-icon wx-video wx-trending-video"></span></a></li> 
    </ul> 
    <ul class="wx-tab-content" data-tab="this_week" style="display:none;" data-vr-zone="Most Popular"> 
  <li data-vr-contentbox=""><a href="/article/superstorm-sandy-photos-then-and-now-20131024" from="62288_MostPopular_1">Superstorm Sandy: Then and Now (EXCLUSIVE PHOTOS)</a></li>
  <li data-vr-contentbox=""><a href="/article/nightmares-fear-factory-terrified-reactions-haunted-house-photos-20131001" from="62288_MostPopular_2">Nightmares Fear Factory: Terrified Reactions at Haunted House (PHOTOS)</a></li> 
  <li data-vr-contentbox=""><a href="/article/eerie-nighttime-shots-abandoned-america-20131023" from="62288_MostPopular_3">Eerie Nighttime Shots of Abandoned America</a></li> 
  <li data-vr-contentbox=""><a href="/article/deadly-venomous-creatures-20131022" from="62288_MostPopular_4">8 Deadly Venomous Creatures and Those Who've Survived (PHOTOS)</a></li> 
  <li data-vr-contentbox=""><a href="/article/fall-foliage-photos-20131021" from="62288_MostPopular_5">Astounding Fall Photos That Will Make You Say 'Wow!'</a></li> 
    </ul> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
</div> 
<div class="wx-map wx-cc-map wx-grid3of6 wx-module pagelet " data-severelocation="false" data-location="BEXX0005" data-location-type="1" data-overlay="" data-zoom="" data-tropical="" data-mapsize="3" data-fragid="frag_newccMap_166739" data-modulecode="beta_CCMap" data-pageid="62288"> 
</div> 
</div>
false
0
```

The problem is `getTodaysForeCast()` keeps saying that the size of `todaysElements` is 0, which it shouldn't be. Could anyone explain me why this is happening or what I'm doing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: According to your print statement, `ForeCastDiv.hasClass("wx-data-part wx-first")` is returning false. Have you checked that exists in the place you expect?

Comment: yes in the output is see that it exists multiple times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jsoup will not accept two combined classes in the `getElementsByClass` method. Try something like:

```
    Elements todaysElements = ForeCastDiv.getElementsByAttributeValueContaining("class", "wx-data-part wx-first");
```

Comment: cogentapps response is better than mine.

Comment: Yes. It solves the problem. But take a look at the congentapps response too. It is more elegant. I voted his answer up.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing two separate class names (separated by a space) to both `hasClass()` and `getElementsByClass()`, both of which can only handle one class at a time.

Try using `select()` instead. It allows you to use complex CSS selectors to find elements, like this:

```
ForeCastDiv.select(".wx-data-part.wx-first")
```

Comment: thanks, but what does the select method returns ? can i also use the Elements class.

Comment: Yes, it returns `Elements`. See: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select%28java.lang.String%29